# main() function live in a .cpp file with the same name as my project in c++

Tags: c++, standards, program-entry-point

I am new in c++ programing and as I am learning, I've saw this hint:

> "It’s a good idea to have your main() function live in a .cpp file with the same name as your project."

I have no clear visual idea how this look. Can someone help me understand how this example work?

And is this example programing standard?

Comment: I like to use main.cpp or driver.cpp for the file where main lives.

Comment: I would not overthink this, it's not like myriads of programmers are going to look for your `main`. Just pick something, `main.cpp` does nicely for example.

Comment: Don't worry about it too much, but the idea is that if you have a project called "CoolGame", you would probably have a folder `CoolGame`, maybe something like a project file from your IDE such as `CoolGame\CoolGame.vcproj` and then the main file with the same name, i.e. `CoolGame\CoolGame.cpp`.

Comment: Ex: your project is called `foo`, they're telling you it is a good idea to put `main` in `foo.cpp`. Whether that is a "good" idea or not is entirely opinion. Personally I like putting mine in a file called `dontlookhere.cpp`

Comment: Heh. :) Tnx  WhozCraig, that was funny :)

Comment: @B.Milovanoski It doesn't matter, it's entirely up to you.

Comment: I usually have source files named after the classes. I then use `main.cpp` to hold the main function. I name the directory after the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have no clear visual idea how this look.

Well, let's say your project is named `MyProject` so you should have a source file `MyProject.cpp` that contains the `main()` function:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "This is MyProject" << std::endl;
}
```

Something like the above is often automatically generated by a sensible IDE that manages your project containing several source and header files.

---

> And is this example programing standard?

There aren't any real standards about how to name source files.

Answer (score 2):

For example your project name is **tutorial,** then your cpp file should be **tutorial.cpp.**

The code for tutorial.cpp will look like:

```
int main() {
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

But I do not think it is a standard or is really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a project you will enter project name and then that name will be your .cbp file 
         you've main.cpp file.
         main() function in your ABC project
         execution always starts from main()
        when you create project its look like

```
#include <iostream>

 int main() {
   std::cout<<"Hello world"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: _"you will enter name and then that name will be your .cpp file"_ How so?

Comment: thanks for correcting its was cbp file and main.cpp file wll create

Comment: Your answer sounds like you are referring to a specific IDE, and how to create a project. Note the question didn't ask for a particular IDE. Something like a `.cbp` file is out of any c++ standards.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is name your file so that you can easily find functions/class, especially on larger project with tens or even hundred of files.

However, the spec has no strict requirement on how to name the file (except perhaps prohibit the use of certain characters). Some people suggests use the project name, some like to use main.c/main.cpp. It's a matter of taste and policy with your team.

Some downside of naming with project name I can think of:

- The project name contain special characters that is not suitable for filename. Try name your project `C & C /2016` and `C & C /2016.cpp` and have fun potentially mess things up.
- The project name is likely to change in the future. IT HAPPENS.

PS. I like to name files according to its content, ie. myclass.h/myclass.cpp contain `myclass`.